# Python - Regular Expression find position of first vowel in a string

Tags: python, regex

How to use regular expression to find the position of first vowel in a string?

e.g. 
    string = 'this is the day!'
'i' is the first vowel and I want to have the position 2 (since i is the 3rd element in the string)

What is I want to find the 2nd vowel, the 3rd, etc.?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for this , it can be done with a simple list comprehension , in 1 loc

```
vowel_pos = [ i for i,v in enumerate(my_string) if v.lower() in ('a','e','i','o','u','y') ]
```

Comment: To make it a bit shorter `v in 'aeiou'`.

Comment: @Vallentin you 're absolutely right , but i think this way is a bit easier to understand